# Highcharts shankey diagram percentage not showing

Tags: highcharts

**Problem:**

The nodeFormat works well for sum (`point.sum`), but does not work for percentage (`point.percentage`).

Working `nodeFormat`:

```
nodeFormat: '{point.name} {point.sum}
```

Not working `nodeFormat`:

```
nodeFormat: '{point.name} {point.percentage}%'
```

**Expected output:**

```
China >> 147 (100)%

US >> 53 (36)%

EU >> 123 (84)%
```

**Formula for expected output:**

```
dataSum = 147
chinaPercentage = chinaData/dataSum*100 = 147/147*100% = 100%
usPercentage = usData/dataSum*100 = 53/147*100% = 36%
euPercentage = euData/dataSum*100 = 84/147*100% = 84%
```

Fiddle reference:
https://jsfiddle.net/8L75ez9n/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `nodeFormatter` function and calculate percentage value:

```
dataLabels: {
  nodeFormatter: function() {
    const point = this.point;
    const percentage = point.linksTo[0] ?
      point.sum / point.linksTo[0].fromNode.sum * 100 :
      100;

    return point.name + ' >> ' + point.sum + ' (' + Math.round(percentage) + ')%'
  }
}
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/q845s7on/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.sankey.dataLabels.nodeFormatter